# Firebase in Android "select from" mutiple collections

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is a "fast" or "less wrong" way to get "dependent" data from Cloud Firestore?

I have two main collections: "users" and "championship".
And a collection named "team" inside every document of a "user".

Every championship is composed of teams, and I'm storing every team in an array of references, like this:

```
"championship": {
    "teams": [
        team_1_ref, team_2_ref, ...
    ]
}
```

By doing this I can get all teams of a championship, but I also want to get the user owner of the team.

I know that I can create a new reference "attribute" named owner for the team and then get the "data" of every user, but there is another way to do this?

Comment: simply save owner id with each team and after retriving data of team get that id and search for owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if there is a way to perform a "join" type query that spans data from multiple collections, that is not possible.  If you have a document with an array, and you want to get all the other documents referred to in that array, you will have to write code to get each one individually.  This is normal for nosql type databases, and it's not as bad as you think, in terms of performance.